# Django: Find all one_to_one relations from queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a queryset of `users`, which are instances of the model `User`.
A second model called `Patient` has a `OneToOneField` named `user`:

```
user = OneToOneField('users.User', on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="patient",
                      blank=True, null=True)
```

The goal is to get a queryset of all patients from the queryset of users.
I thought that by using the `related_name` would be enough, meaning:

```
queryset_of_users=User.objects.filter(main_group='patients')
queryset_of_patients=queryset_of_users.patient
```

but it seems this is not it since I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'patient'

Any ideas?

Comment: [k.patient for k in users.objects.all()]

Comment: Would `User.objects.all().values_list("patient", flat=True)` do what you want?

Comment: @kpie --> `User.patient.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no patient`

Comment: `for user in User.objects.all(): if hasattr(user,'patient'): user.patient` will work even if user has no patient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it,

It works by making a second query:

```
queryset_of_patients=Patient.objects.filter(user__in=queryset_of_users)
```